# C# Solution with Web and GUI projects

Tags: c#, user-interface, web

I am trying to build an system in C# for all modules which has a both a web site and a GUI interface. I have created two projects in the same solution. The two modules will need to talk to each. That is why I am putting them together. Maybe it is not necessary for them to be in the same solution but both need to run at the same time during testing and deployment. Presently when have compiled both modules but they are also using Entity Framework core. I have just started the web part and it cannot add the first migration. It complains that

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Project '..\opencreditfederation2_23_web\opencreditfederation2_23_web.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp3.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'.    opencreditfederation2_23

Now when I try to get these things matched I am stuck because the web application only offers versions of netcoreapp and the GUI app only offers .NETFramework items. Is there a way round this I should I been taking a different approach altogether?

When I try to match them up this is what I see:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFiQl.png)

Comment: One project you have the target set to Core and the other to Net 4.7.2.   Go to VS menu Project : Properties and change the Target so both are Core.

Comment: That is what I tried but core is not offered. I am confused by the situation and wondering why it is not offered since it is selected in the web application. I am going to try pasting what I see.

Comment: The last option is "Install other Frameworks".   Try creating new project and see if it is offered

Comment: If I click "Install other Frameworks"the drop down list closes and the target framework is still set to .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: I took a step back and removed the web project from the solution before add another one. This time I saw an option to select the Net 4.7.2 frame during the initial set up process. This seems to have solved that problem. Not sure if you would have suggested this but your comment guided me here, thank you. I would be interested to know why I could not make the adjustment after the project was created.

This is resolved from my point of view. How do I mark it so and thank you for your comment?